# Book about a world of women where a man crash lands trying to find his way home?

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in 1989 and got it from my high school library. It had an interesting cover of a ship on the waters with a man and a woman on the cover looking at the sun. It was called something like underneath the sun or something to that effect but for the life of me, I can't find it anywhere regardless of the search term I use. I don't know what the exact year of the novel's publication was, but it couldn't have been more than 10 years earlier, so probably mid-late 70's to possibly mid-late 80's.

The story was about a pilot that crash lands on a planet and quickly finds that it's all women. They run everything and men are nowhere to be seen. Later he finds out that there are men and they are kept in very pampered conditions and used for, well procreation and maybe even pleasure but mostly as stud stock basically. The women have no problem being intimate with each other which is common and they are soldiers, leaders, so on and so forth, they run everything. So he is under the protection of this lady captain of a ship who finds his man-oriented world fascinating and gives him some slack to be more than the men they usually have.

He goes on quests with them, they find him very capable but ultimately he falls in love with the captain because he is not sure he will ever be able to leave the planet and might as well make the best of it. They find ruins that show evidence that maybe at some point this planet was more dominated by men but something catastrophic happened causing them to die off and so now they are a rare commodity. I remember I picked this up just on a whim and I couldn't put it down, it was far more interesting than I am able to convey here and I have always wanted to re-read it again as an adult with a lifetime of experience to see if my view of the story is still the same as it was when I read it the first time but no luck finding it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there "snoo snoo" involved?

Comment: @Richard forgive me if I am being dense but I am not sure what you mean, sorry :(

Comment: It's from a futurama episode set on a planet of the amazons. Fry, Zapp and Kiff are sentenced to death by snoo snoo.

Comment: @Richard oh I see, no unfortunately this predates Futurama :) maybe they can tell me where they got the idea, it might just help me figure this out.

Comment: Not Poul Anderson's *Virgin Planet*, that one has no men at all (except the hero), just women. In Evelyn E. Smith's *The Perfect Planet* the women do have stay-at-home men, but they are visited by a two-person team from offworld, a man and a women, and I don't recall a crash landing, so it's not that either.

Comment: It's more of a collection of stories, but could it possibly be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Amazons_of_Darkover

Comment: are you sure it wasn't an adult movie? :)

Comment: Thank you all, you are awesome. @MaurizioIndenmark as I clearly indicated it was a novel and not a movie, porn or otherwise but thank you, it made me smile.

Comment: Being the only man on a planet full of women would be either awesome or terrifying. Not sure which.

Comment: @Omegacron, well that the cool thing in this book, you see how they are treated as royalty for the purposes of pleasure and breeding, but otherwise pretty much kept pets in a way. Then comes this man who is completely different and the primary woman in this book at first has trouble with that but in time comes to sort of appreciate it and sees its potential.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You *might* be looking for [To Stand Beneath the Sun](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451142381). It was published in 1986 and the title obviously "matches" your criteria. (I found it by searching on Amazon with "beneath sun science fiction", so if this is the novel a single additional word can make a significant difference in searching!)

The cover does not have a woman looking at the Sun, but the social position of women and men does match, the captain was the man's protector and did allow him significant freedoms.

The book's setting also did not have a previous time when men were equally common, instead the sex ratio was planned as part of the colonization effort. (Apparently, the space travelers had temporal stasis fields but not uterine replicators!)

The man discovers (thanks to a solar-powered laptop-like device that he had) that an escape pod from the colony ship had landed on land. This pod could be used to waken the colony ship whose orbit was slowly decaying (which was why his pod was jettisoned). Reaching the pod required crossing a substantial desert.

Answer (score 0):

*First answer seems right, but the book seems to be a copy of a much earlier Gene Roddenberry Story that was made into three movies starring John Saxon and Diana Muldaur...*

**Strange New World - 1975**
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073754/*

**Planet Earth - 1974**
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072000/

**Genesis II - 1973**

I remember watching these when they first came out on on CBS.

Comment: The question is asking about a book. If the book in question is based on earlier material, you might want to make this a comment on the earlier answer.

Comment: Thank you for the information but I have to agree with @Blackwood on this, I was simply looking for the book, not any potential materials external to it that might have predated it or whatnot. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt, you are looking for Poul Anderson's "Virgin Planet". I too got it from a high school library, and remember it as you do. Yellow jacket, black title, a very simple hardcover.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you explain in greater detail how this book matches the OP's description, and why you believe it's a better match than the existing accepted answer?

Comment: IIRC, "Virgin Planet" featured a world totally without men (except for the one who landed), not one where men were rare and kept as stud and sometimes sexual pleasure objects.  I also remember no hint of lesbianism.

Comment: It sounds like the premise for the book you mentioned might be very similar but I have confirmed and already purchased the book and re-read it and it is the one I was looking for. Thank you for the input though, I will check it out as well.